# Linear layer (convolution layer) in PCANET

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network, pca

In PCANET

What is the advantage of applying 2 convolution layers with out pooling layer between them?

What is the task of the second pca layer?

Comment: PCANet: A Simple Deep Learning Baseline for Image Classification